# Adding image to database from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, image, sql

In my form.php file I have added a field for an image to be inserted.

```
$fieldset->addField('main_image', 'image', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Upload a Main Image'),
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'main_image',
    ));
```

I'm not sure how to add this field to the database with my sql upgrade script?

So far I have this

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
addColumn($installer->getTable('blog/blog'), 'main_image', array(
    'type'      =>

    ))
```

As you can see I didn't know what type to put it as, I've done a fair bit of googling and haven't found anything.

New to magento so thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it as `VARCHAR(255)` which is similar to other fields in Magento like the `image` field in `catalog_category_flat_...` tables.  It should save the value of the relative path of your image in your `media` directory and be big enough to account for a variety of filenames.

Don't forget the `->` before `addColumn(`

TIP: Remember that all the features in the Magento core are added in essentially the same way as any extension you write so it can often help to look at similar features in the modules in `app/code/core/Mage/` to see how the Magento developers did it.